# Getting the ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list when trying to remove a value from a list

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, iteration

Im trying to get this to work below but when i run the code i keep getting this error

> Traceback (most recent call last): 
>   File "F:/Computer Sci/Mathematics for Computing/Assignment 2/Assignment2.py", line 15, in 
>           array1.remove([7,2,3,5]) 
>   ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

```
array1 = [[7,2,3,5],[7,2,90,0],[7,2,3,90],[7,3,3,5]] 
array2 = [[1,2,4,8],[1,90,4,0],[7,2,90,3],[4,2,4,5]]

for x in range (0,4):
    if x == 0:
        continue
    for y in range (0,4):
        if array1[0][y] < array1[x][y]:
            array1.remove([7,2,3,5])
```

Comment: error message is pretty clear, what are you expecting here?

Comment: I don't understand why it is telling that there is an error with "array1.remove([7,2,3,5])" when [7,2,3,5] is a real value in the list despite it telling me its not?

Comment: I assume it is being removed in an early iteration of the loop and then you are attempting to remove it again in a subsequent iteration.

Comment: how would i go about ending the loop upon the removal of the value?

Comment: If don"t wanna include the 0 in the `range` start from 1 using `range(1, 4)` https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range  and you can iterate through the list directly without using indices `for elm in array`

Comment: Do you need to break out of both loops, or just the inner ?

Comment: I need to break out of both loops once the value has been removed

Comment: Could you please tell us what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: @taoufikA im trying to create a programme that will find the dominant strategy in a game theory scenario and these two arrays represent each players different strategies available to them

Answer (score 1):

As I did say in the comment your code can be improved

You can use a function and return once your condition is satisfied

```
def func(array1, to_remove):
    for lst in array1:
        for index, n in enumerate(lst):
            if array1[0][index] < n:
                array1.remove(to_remove)
                return True
    return False
```

Or use a flag

```
flag = False
for lst in array1:
    for index, n in enumerate(lst):
        if array1[0][index] < n:
            array1.remove([7,2,3,5])
            flag = True
            break
    if flag:
        break
```

Comment: If you're gonna make it a function, you might as well pass the element as a parameter as well.

Comment: @nlsdfnbch yes, why not ?

Comment: pretty as a picture now. ;)

Comment: @taoufikA Can you please explain how the function works that you created?

Comment: It takes the array and the element that you wanna remove and once it removes it it will return (Updated) True else it will return False

Comment: @taoufikA im not sure if your solution would work because i would need to remove the entire list [7,2,3,5]

Comment: It would, you have to pass it as a parameter func(array1, [7,2,3,5])

Comment: @taoufikA would i have to make the variable array1 global first? EDIT, i cannot enter a list into the function (func(array1, [7,2,3,5]) as it brings up a syntax error issue with the squared bracket

Comment: nn just pass it as param `func(array1, [7,2,3,5])`